# Error using ImageJ library to reduce greylevels

Tags: java, image-processing

i'm trying to use the ImageJ library to produce an output image with 4 greylevels and display it but i'm getting an error in the reduceBy method in this line

```
 out.getPixel(r, c) = (in.getPixel(r, c) / factor) * factor;
```

It says the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable, but surely it is a variable?

import ij.ImagePlus;
import iptoolkit.*;

public class ReduceGreyLevelsIJ {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String imageDir = "C:/Users/John/Dropbox/finalYear/Project/Leaves/";        
    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();   

    ImagePlus src = new ImagePlus(imageDir +"ashLeafBW.tif");
    ImagePlus dst1 = new ImagePlus();
    src.show("Original");

    reduceBy(64, src, dst1);
    dst1.show("4 Grey Levels");
}

static void reduceBy(int factor, ImagePlus in, ImagePlus out) {
    for (int r = 0; r < in.getHeight(); r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < in.getWidth(); c++) {
            out.getPixel(r, c) = (in.getPixel(r, c) / factor) * factor;
        } // c
    } // r
}  // reduceBy
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a variable. It is a call to a method that returns an int, which is by no means the same as a variable. Do not confuse data types with variables.

I guess that you want to retrieve a value from in and, after transforming it, store it in out. For that purpose, you will need to do something like this (I haven't tested it, but this is at least the logic you must follow).

```
int p = (in.getPixel(r, c) / factor) * factor;
out.putPixel(r,c,p);
```